# Rust diferença entre std::ops para operadores normais

Tags: desempenho, rust

Olá estou buscando otimizar operações matemáticas em meu programa,
explorando os módulos do Rust encontrei o **std::ops**.

Minha duvida é a seguinte.

```rust
use std::ops::{Add};
fn main() {
    let x = 10;
    println!{"{}",x.add(2)}; // retorna 12
    println!{"{}",x + 2}; // retorna 12
}
```

Em ambos os casos a saída é a mesma

**Porem tem alguma diferença entre o desempenho do** `x.add(2)` **para o** `x + 2` **?**

Observação há outros operadores como **% , / , - , *** no modulo **std:ops**;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Não, não existe nenhuma diferença de desempenho (no exemplo da pergunta e demais operadores da observação) quando você compila com a opção *release*.

---

As operações aritméticas em `std::ops` são definidas através de *traits*, por exemplo, a operação de soma:

```
#[doc(alias = "+")]
pub trait Add<Rhs=Self> {
    /// The resulting type after applying the `+` operator.
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    type Output;

    /// Performs the `+` operation.
    #[must_use]
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    fn add(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output;
}
```

A função `add` recebe 2 parâmetros do mesmo tipo (`Rhs=Self`) e retorna um resultado do mesmo tipo, também.

A implementação para os tipos primitivos (`usize u8 u16 u32 u64 u128 isize i8 i16 i32 i64 i128 f32 f64`) são definidas na macro `add_impl`:

```
impl Add for $t {
    type Output = $t;

    #[inline]
    #[rustc_inherit_overflow_checks]
    fn add(self, other: $t) -> $t { self + other }
}
```

Ou seja, ela implementa a soma através do próprio operador `+` e, como existe o atributo `#[inline]`, o compilador no modo *release*, otimiza o código e não gera **nenhuma** diferença de desempenho.

Referência: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcore/ops/arith.rs

---

Caso você compile o código no modo *debug* (sem nenhuma otimização), existe uma pequena diferença no código binário gerado que resulta em perda de desempenho.

Para o código abaixo:

```
use std::ops::{Add};

// Lê uma string numérica digitada pelo usuário e converte para inteiro de 64 bits
fn get_number() -> i64 {
    let mut buf = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut buf).unwrap();
    buf.trim().parse::<i64>().unwrap()
}

// Função principal
fn main() {
    let x = get_number();
    let y = get_number();

    let opsadd = x.add(y);   // Soma através do método add
    let diradd = x + y;   // Soma direta

    println!("Direto: {}", diradd);
    println!("Ops: {}", opsadd);
}
```

Sem otimização, ele gera no executável uma chamada (*call*) à função `add` para obter o resultado e armazenar em `opsadd` e, para o `diradd` a soma é feita diretamente sem chamadas.

Esssa chamada é necessária devido a função ser compilada sem o *[inline]* no modo sem otimização:

```
140002a20:   48 81 ec 28 01 00 00    sub    $0x128,%rsp
140002a27:   e8 c4 fe ff ff          callq  0x1400028f0      ; lê entrada do usuário
140002a2c:   48 89 44 24 68          mov    %rax,0x68(%rsp)  ; salva em x
140002a31:   e8 ba fe ff ff          callq  0x1400028f0      ; lê entrada do usuário
140002a36:   48 89 44 24 70          mov    %rax,0x70(%rsp)  ; salva em y
140002a3b:   48 8b 4c 24 68          mov    0x68(%rsp),%rcx
140002a40:   48 8b 54 24 70          mov    0x70(%rsp),%rdx  ; Carrega os 2 valores e...
140002a45:   e8 b6 ed ff ff          callq  0x140001800      ; ...chama o add
140002a4a:   48 89 44 24 78          mov    %rax,0x78(%rsp)  ; salva o resultado em opsadd
140002a4f:   48 8b 44 24 68          mov    0x68(%rsp),%rax  ; obtém o valor de x
140002a54:   48 03 44 24 70          add    0x70(%rsp),%rax  ; soma direto (+) com y
140002a59:   0f 90 c1                seto   %cl
140002a5c:   f6 c1 01                test   $0x1,%cl
140002a5f:   48 89 44 24 60          mov    %rax,0x60(%rsp)  ; salva o resultado em diradd
140002a64:   0f 85 51 01 00 00       jne    0x140002bbb
```

Com otimização, a soma é feita diretamente e o compilador, inclusive, "entende" que o valor de `opsadd` e `diradd` são o mesmo:

```
 1400014b0:   56                      push   %rsi
 1400014b1:   57                      push   %rdi
 1400014b2:   48 83 ec 78             sub    $0x78,%rsp
 1400014b6:   e8 d5 fe ff ff          callq  0x140001390      ; lê entrada do usuário
 1400014bb:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi        ; salva em x
 1400014be:   e8 cd fe ff ff          callq  0x140001390      ; lê entrada do usuário
 1400014c3:   48 01 f0                add    %rsi,%rax        ; já soma direto com y
 1400014c6:   48 89 44 24 38          mov    %rax,0x38(%rsp)  ; salva o resultado em opsadd
 1400014cb:   48 89 44 24 40          mov    %rax,0x40(%rsp)  ; salva o mesmo resultado em diradd
```

Portanto, sem otimização existe uma operação de `call` "a mais", que gera um custo de desempenho durante a execução e, com otimização, esse custo não existe.

Comment: Entendido  achei que teria alguma diferença , por exemplo em cálculos extensos como uma integral ou derivada achei que utilizando esses recursos haveria uma otimização.

Comment: Notei também que a operadores booleanos nos módulos do std::ops , como < , > , &&, || , != etc... O mesmo caso seria valido então :)

Comment: Sim, é válido sim para os operadores booleanos, que seguem a mesma lógica